# How to combine multiple *ngifs?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Hello I just want a ng if with three ouputs to print in a table.

Now i have this syntax:

```
<td><div *ngIf="todo.diffDays >90">ninety</div> </td>
```

I would to display in a column this ouputs

```
if diffDays >90 => ninety
if diffDays >180 => hundredeighty
and if diffdays >300 =>theehundred
```

How to combine them ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use switchCase for that?

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't even need an `*ngIf` if you just want to display for everything `> 90`. 
You could just do something like this:

```
<div> 
   {{ 
      diffdays > 300 ? "threehundred" : 
      diffDays > 180 ? "hundredeighty" :
      diffDays > 90 ? "ninety" : "Less than 90" 
   }}
</div>
```

This essentially reads:

```
if > 300 display "threehundred", otherwise continue...
if > 180 display "hundredeighty, otherwise continue...
if > 90 display "ninety"...
if none satisfied display "Less than 90"
```

Comment: No i want to make more than >90.
How to implement that to check all values? I tried switchcase but it doesnt worked

Comment: @BVB1392 This does check for `> 90` and if it is `< 90` it displays "Less than 90" - if you want it to be blank then just swap `"Less than 90"` to `""`.

Comment: @BVB1392 Can you please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your issue - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` multiple times for this:

```
<div *ngIf="todo.diffDays > 90">ninety</div>
<div *ngIf="todo.diffDays > 180">hundredeighty</div>
<div *ngIf="todo.diffDays > 300">threehundred</div>
```

Comment: ok thats good but now i will get  just one value and not multiple:. if i define >90 than ninety and > 180 than hundredeighty he give me two values

Answer (score 0):

First you have declare a days variable in component class.

```
export class AppComponent {

 public days: number;

 constructor() {

    this.days = 90; // Assign value
   }
}
```

call days as shown in below div tag.

```
<td>

<div *ngIf="todo.diffDays > days">{{days}}</div> 

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this logic in your model. There's many different ways to implements this, it depends on what you need precisely

TypeScript:

```
foo(val: number): string {
    if (val > 90) {
        return "ninety";
    }
    if (val > 180) {
        return "hundredeighty";
    }
    return "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{foo(todo.diffDays)}}</div>
```

Comment: ok thank you !It works.
Do you happen to know how i can combine it with an another table column? like todo.(anything)

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: So maybe get an another column in the if condition and compare this columns.